# Quicksort in C++ with std::vector, EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 2

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, exc-bad-access, stdvector

VS Code catches this exception when I run my quicksort algorithm: 
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffffc). This happens on the first line in partition():

```cpp
int i = p;
```

I have tried to implement the Cormen algorithm: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~lacher/courses/COP4531/lectures/sorts/slide09.html

Why can I not access the variable p? Is it released, and if so, how do I fix this?

### My code

```cpp
//.h file
void sortVector(vector<int> &vec, int p=0, int r=-2);
int partition(vector<int> &vec, int p, int r);

//.cpp file
int partition(vector<int> &vec, int p, int r) {
    int i = p;
    for (int j = p; j <r-1; ++j) {
        if (vec[j] < vec[r-1]) {
            swap(vec[j], vec[r-1]);
            i++;
        }
        swap(vec[i], vec[r-1]);
    }
    return i;
}

void sortVector(vector<int> &vec, int p, int r) {
    if (r == -2) {
        r = vec.size();
    }
    if (p-r<1) {
        int q = partition(vec, p, r);
        sortVector(vec, p, q);
        sortVector(vec, q+1, r);
    }

}
```

*I am including "std_lib_facilities.h" from Stroustrup: Programming Principles and Practice Using C++.*

Comment: The most likely cause of the crash is Stack Overflow. `p` or `i` (probably both) is no longer inside valid memory. This is because of a bug elsewhere, Faruk's answer proves an excellent candidate bug and solution, preventing the recursion from ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `swap(vec[i], vec[r-1]);` out of `for` loop.

It should be like this -

```
//.cpp file
int partition(vector<int> &vec, int p, int r) {
    int i = p;
    for (int j = p; j <r-1; ++j) {
        if (vec[j] < vec[r-1]) {
            swap(vec[j], vec[r-1]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    swap(vec[i], vec[r-1]);

    return i;
}
```

Comment: This provides a great example showing that the program's crash site is most often not where the bug is. This is a bug worth pointing out even if there are more bugs lurking in the code not provided.

Comment: Thank you, this was one of several bugs. I will edit the post to show the working code as well.

Answer (score 1):

There were problems in both functions:

partition():

- first swap had wrong arguments.
- second swap had to be moved out of
  the for-loop (suggested by Faruk Hossain)
- `if (vec[j] < vec[r-1])` became `if (vec[j] <= vec[r-1])`

sortVector():

- `if (p-r<1)` became if `(p<r)`

Working code below.

```
int partition(vector<int> &vec, int p, int r) {
    int i = p;
    for (int j = p; j <r-1; ++j) {
        if (vec[j] <= vec[r-1]) {
            swap(vec[i], vec[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    swap(vec[i], vec[r-1]);
    return i;
}
void sortVector(vector<int> &vec, int p, int r) {
    if (r == -2) {
        r = vec.size();
    }
    if (r>p) {
        int q = partition(vec, p, r);
        sortVector(vec, p, q);
        sortVector(vec, q+1, r);
    }

}
```